# Making a GET request to read the contents of a file online but I am getting a connection refused error

Tags: node.js, get, httprequest

I am trying to read content a JSON file to decide if I need to update another file or not. The url where the current version of the JSON file I need to update is located here: https://mtgjson.com/json/version.json. This is my code:

```
var url = https://mtgjson.com/json/version.json
https.get(url,function(res){
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (data) {
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(jsonObject)
        var version = jsonObject.toString();
        if(version != currentVersion){
            console.log(currentVersion);
            console.log("new version... UPDATING");
            currentVersion = version;
            console.log(currentVersion);
            update();
        }
        else{
            console.log("no Update needed");
            callback();
        }
    });
});
```

The error I get is

```
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
```

My guess is that is because I am making an invalid request. Reading the headers of the file I am trying to access I see this:

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
```

So my guess is that I can't read the file because I am making a bad request? Or maybe I simply can't access the file? I don't know what to do.

Comment: aside from the syntax error in your code, `url` not being a string. Your code works fine, I tried it and I get a valid response: `3.15.2`. I'm not able to reproduce your error. Is that all your code?

Comment: Oh yes, in my code url is a string but when I copied here I deleted the quotation marks. I will try again but I am getting an error. I will try again.

Comment: I dont get any error using Postman, the error appears when using node.js and the code above... weird.

Comment: Only the above code, without nothing else? Because with that code, I'm not getting any error, your code looks good. Post your full code.

Comment: Yup, I isolated it, just with that code.

Comment: what is https? is it the https module? or something like axios?

Comment: `callback` doesn't exist, quotes missing, post the exact code, because I don't see any `require`...

Comment: oh wait a minute, the url module and the url from the site had the same name. That was it. Thanks :)

Comment: always post the *relavent* code :)

Comment: yeah that's something I need to always do!